Restore a backup for an Azure WordPress website
Solved! Solution below, here's the original problem:
I accidentally set an Elementor page in WordPress to global and can't access my WordPress (WP) admin page or login page. The global Elementor page shows for every URL option to view the page.
I have a Microsoft Azure developers account and am trying to restore a backup or disable enough functionality so that I can access my Azure WordPress dashboard and remove the global settings on the webpage in question. I'd appreciate any help, thank you in advance!
I restored a backup according to the following Microsoft Website and it was successful, but my page still hasn't changed. It only displays the global Elementor page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup?tabs=portal
In wp-content I tried to change all the relevant plug-in folders and then the plug-in folder itself to disable Elementor and all plug-ins. I also looked at my page source, but under 'source' and 'network' I could not find any Elementor or plug-in files to disable. My goal was to disable Elementor so that I could access the WordPress admin dashboard and remove the global settings for the webpage.  Though I prefer to just restore a backup copy of the website from two days ago.
Solution:
I figured this out, finally!  Solution.  I needed to restore backups from both Azure WordPress App and Azure MySQL Flexible Server.
Restoring the backup from my Azure WordPress App was pretty straightforward.  Under App Services, pick the app name of the WordPress app, under Settings there is a Backups options.  Pick the backup you need and click the restore icon.
Go back to your home/dashboard and find your associated Azure Database for MySQL Flexible Server.  Under Settings there is a Backup and Restore option.  Find the date/time you want to restore and click fast restore.  On the next page, most of the fields are auto-populated.  You'll need to create a new database name, such as (your current database)-db-restored.
After your new database for MySQL Flexible Server deploys, look for these settings.  You'll be using these values to update the MySQL database information in your WordPress app:
DATABASE_HOST or WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: New server name
DATABASE_NAME or WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: database name (likely unchanged, in my case it was the same)
DATABASE_USERNAME or WORDPRESS_DB_USER: username. In my case, these were the same
DATABASE_PASSWORD or WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: this is probably the same, but I reset the password (see top line on the configuration page) to be the same.  Below I'll explain where you get the current password (for your old database for MySQL Flexible Server).
Go back to your Home dashboard, pick your App Service WordPress App, and under Configuration, click Environmental Variables.  Here you can look up the current password (for your old database MySQL Flexible Server) and return to the (yourcurrent database)-db-restored database for MySQL Flexible Server and reset the password to it.  Again, not sure you need to do this, it may remain the same.
Head back to Environmental Variables and change the fields above to match DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USERNAME, and DATABASE_PASSWORD as needed.
You can go into wp-config.php if you want, but in my case which is likely for others, those variables are dynamically assigned.  If you want to check your wp-config.php, under your WordPress App go to Development Tools, Advanced Tools, and site wwwroot to look at the wp-config.php file. You shouldn't need to change it if you see variables for the fields above.

I figured this out, finally!

Your solution should go in the Answers section below as a self-answer, and not in the body of your question; this makes the solution itself more easily findable on the page for future visitors to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

I tried, but I was 1,700+ words over in my comment allowance. Very minimal allowance where I wrote "I figured this out, finally!"  Is there some limitation when you are the first to comment on your own post?

All posts are limited in size, but questions and answers have a 30,000 character limit. If you can fit it in your question as an addendum to what you already had there, then it certainly would fit in an answer. Comments are significantly more limited in length and aren’t intended to house anything more than ephemeral meta-discussion about the posts they appear under.

Thanks for that clarification!  Posted the solution as an answer. I'm a newbie on this forum, too bad someone down-voted the post because it took a lot of research to figure this out.

Solution: I figured this out, finally! Solution. I needed to restore backups from both Azure WordPress App and Azure MySQL Flexible Server.
Restoring the backup from my Azure WordPress App was pretty straightforward. Under App Services, pick the app name of the WordPress app, under Settings there is a Backups options. Pick the backup you need and click the restore icon. Go back to your home/dashboard and find your associated Azure Database for MySQL Flexible Server. Under Settings there is a Backup and Restore option. Find the date/time you want to restore and click fast restore. On the next page, most of the fields are auto-populated. You'll need to create a new database name, such as (your current database)-db-restored.
After your new database for MySQL Flexible Server deploys, look for these settings. You'll be using these values to update the MySQL database information in your WordPress app: DATABASE_HOST or WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: New server name DATABASE_NAME or WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: database name (likely unchanged, in my case it was the same) DATABASE_USERNAME or WORDPRESS_DB_USER: username. In my case, these were the same DATABASE_PASSWORD or WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: this is probably the same, but I reset the password (see top line on the configuration page) to be the same. Below I'll explain where you get the current password (for your old database for MySQL Flexible Server). Go back to your Home dashboard, pick your App Service WordPress App, and under Configuration, click Environmental Variables. Here you can look up the current password (for your old database MySQL Flexible Server) and return to the (yourcurrent database)-db-restored database for MySQL Flexible Server and reset the password to it. Again, not sure you need to do this, it may remain the same.
Head back to Environmental Variables and change the fields above to match DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USERNAME, and DATABASE_PASSWORD as needed.
You can go into wp-config.php if you want, but in my case which is likely for others, those variables are dynamically assigned. If you want to check your wp-config.php, under your WordPress App go to Development Tools, Advanced Tools, and site wwwroot to look at the wp-config.php file. You shouldn't need to change it if you see variables for the fields above.
